# How to connect with FIWARE from iOS app

Tags: objective-c, swift, fiware

I am working with iOS project which need to login with FIWARE users. Does anyone experience this?

Thanks,
Diego

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert in Objective-C (nor swift). Nevertheless, the FIWARE Idm implements stardard OAUth2, so you should be able to authenticate your users using FIWARE by using an OAuth2 library for your programming language.

You can find documentation about the FIWARE IDM at:
http://fiware-idm.readthedocs.org

Additionally, FIWARE GEs implement REST APIs so you can access them with an stadard HTTP Client.